# lost connection after multiple requests (threads) VB.NET/win xp sp3?

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcp

I Have a function that returns some headers called get headers

and I start multi threads using

```
 For i = 0 to 255

 Dim t As Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf Getheaders))

t.Start("192.168.1." + i.tostring)
```

the 255 threads start at same time and return good results but after this I cant re-use connexion it will be lost from vb.net and other browsers since waiting for some time or repair connexion

I HAVE PATCHED TCPIP.SYS FILE TO 65000 CONNEXIONS

Any helps will be Appreciated !!!

Comment: How does the thread look like?

Comment: the thread is a function with parmateter ip it makes request on the ip and get headers from response